# Scaling a Docker Container While Consuming the messages from Kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a Docker Container which consumes the messages from kafka broker.
In that Container Code, I am creating a consumer group to consume the messages from multiple topics. I haven't tried scaling the docker container, But I want to know what happens if i scale the docker container, Will it consume the messages with the same consumer group?

Comment: Why not scale the thread pool inside the container first?

Answer (score 2):

If they all have the same consumer group then the messages will be load balanced between the containers. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers